# MySQL sort by sum multiple columns in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

#### Users

```
| id | name  |
|----|-------|
| 1  | One   |
| 2  | Two   |
| 3  | Three |
```

#### Likes

```
| id | user_id | like  |
|----|---------|-------|
| 1  | 1       | 3     |
| 2  | 1       | 5     |
| 3  | 2       | 1     |
| 4  | 3       | 2     |
```

#### Transations

```
| id | user_id | transaction |
|----|---------|-------------|
| 1  | 1       | -1          |
| 2  | 2       | 5           |
| 3  | 2       | -1          |
| 4  | 3       | 10          |
```

I need get sum of likes.like and transations.transation for each user and then sort it by its result.

I was able to do it for users and likes:

```
select users.*, sum(likes.like) as points
from `users`
inner join `likes` on `likes`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
group by `users`.`id`
order by points desc
```

But then I add transactions table like this:

```
select users.*, (sum(likes.like)+sum(transactions.`transaction`)) as points
from `users`
inner join `likes` on `likes`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
inner join `transactions` on `transactions`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
group by `users`.`id`
order by points desc
```

It is show wrong results.

I expecting to see:

```
| id | name  | points |
|----|-------|--------|
| 3  | Three | 12     |
| 1  | One   | 7      |
| 2  | Two   | 5      |
```

But get this instead:

```
| id | name  | points |
|----|-------|--------|
| 3  | Three | 12     |
| 1  | One   | 6      |
| 2  | Two   | 5      |
```

So, how sort users by sum likes.like and transations.transation?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the result you get and the expected result.

Comment: I don't understand the likes table. Can you explain what it does?

Comment: How many times user liked page, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's not a 1-to-1 relationships between `transactions` and `likes`, I think you need to use subqueries:

```
select users.*,
    (select sum(points) from likes where user_id = users.id) as points,
    (select sum(transaction) from transactions where user_id = users.id) as transactions
from users
order by points desc
```

**Updated** after more explanation of requirements:

```
select users.*,
    (select sum(points) from likes where user_id = users.id) +
    (select sum(transaction) from transactions where user_id = users.id) as points
from users
order by points desc
```

Comment: Wrong. In your results One, has 8 points, but must be 7 (3+8 from likes and -1 from trans)

Comment: OK, so you just need to add both of those together.  I'll update the example.  I assume you mean 3+5 from likes...

Comment: Looks like it is work, thank you! Any suggestions for performance?

Comment: You should have an index on the `user_id` column for both `transactions` and `likes`